# How to make source code file be ready under home/klee when use Klee docker image

Tags: docker, docker-container, klee

I have Klee installed as a docker image. I am trying to follow the first tutorial of KLEE. I am wondering instead of inputing source codes by echo "int main(int argn, char** argv) { return 0; }" > test.c, how can I input the .c file to home/klee?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to make use of docker volume;

Comment: There are some default directories can be bind mounted into docker containers on Mac, but I still do not know how to use it in Klee container. Always have the error: no such file or directory